# Is holding the data loaded in an AsyncTaskLoader a good idea?

Tags: android, loader

I am making a simple application that will load some data and display it for editing.

The process could take some time so I decided to use a loader (instead of a service which I usually do) to load said data.

I am using an `AsyncTaskLoader` like this:

```
 class DataLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<LoadResult> {

 }
```

where `LoadResult` is a custom class that looks something like this:

```
class LoadResult {
    Exception error;
    List<Entry> entries;
    List<Option> options;
    List<User> users;
}
```

I have been reading up on loaders and it seems that the recommended strategy is something along these lines for its implementation:

```
public class DataLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<LoadResult> {
    LoadResult _result;
    boolean _changed = false;

    public DataLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        if (_changed) {
            _result = null;
            forceLoad();
        } else {
            deliverResult(_result);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public LoadResult loadInBackground() {
        //load stuff here
        _result = ...
        _changed = false;
        return _result;
    }

    public void notify_data_changed() {
       _changed = true;
    }
}
```

Now this works ok, but I'm worried because the activity that receives the result also has a fragment attached that will contain the data once loaded, and thus if I follow the above mentioned strategy the data will be stored on multiple memory places

On the other hand, whenever OnCreate is called (due to configuration changes for example) if I don't follow the above strategy, the application will reload all data even though there is no updates to it.

What would be a good compromise so that I won't be reloading data all the time?

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Consider using the new lifecycle-aware components instead, such as `ViewModel`. [Here's a nice blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/lifecycle-aware-data-loading-with-android-architecture-components-f95484159de4) from an Android framework dev.

Comment: wow this looks very interesting, thank you for bringing it to my attention, I will definitely give it a try

Comment: since I am early in my project, I replaced things with livedata and viewmodels, it works great, and it is really good , but I will also be using asynctaskloaders to save my data , and I haven't found a way to do that with AndroidViewModel